# copy specific row data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new here as well as new to vba.
Im trying to copy the row based on selected columns.

I have used useform to get ranges from users to copy details of those data to next sheet.

I have written code to get the address of the range ( which is entered on userfrom)

Now when i try to copy the row, its just copying the S.no without any other details.

```
Sub copy_data()


    If pass1 = 1 Then
        Sheets("I yr").Range(cellFrom1 & ":" & cellTo1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")
    End If
    
    If pass2 = 1 Then
        Sheets("II yr").Range(cellFrom2 & ":" & cellTo2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")
    End If
    
    If pass3 = 1 Then
        Sheets("III yr").Range(cellFrom3 & ":" & cellTo3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")
    End If
    
    If pass4 = 1 Then
        Sheets("IV yr").Range(cellFrom4 & ":" & cellTo4).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8:B37")
    End If



End Sub
```

here

```
cellFrom1 = Sheets("I yr").Range("N4").Value  //N4 will have from address of the s.no selected
cellTo1 = Sheets("I yr").Range("O4").Value   //O4 will to address of the s.no selected
```

I tried this code, but it's just copying the S.No ,not with that respected details

the data format will be like

| S.no | regNo | Name | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 921 | aaa | II |
| 2 | 922 | bbb | II |
| 3 | 923 | ccc | II |
| 4 | 924 | ddd | II |
| 5 | 925 | eee | II |
| ... |  |  |  |

If i giving the range from 3 -5 it should copy the data like

| S.no | Reg No | Name | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 923 | ccc | II |
| 4 | 924 | ddd | II |
| 5 | 925 | eee | II |

Comment: Your question is unclear as there is no question. Also you say in the text `cellFrom1 = $A$2` and `cellTo =$A$20` but in your picture it is `$A$3` and ̀ $A$22`. You say *"it's just copying the S.No ,not with that respected details"* but which details do you mean? The columns `name` and `year`? • Please describe what your code does versus what you expet it to do. It is very unclear what exactly is going wrong. Pleas [edit] your question, a comment will very likely not be enough context.

Comment: values mentioned are just for samples. I want to get the results like which i showed at top

Comment: If I want details of 15th row ,i mean the data with s.no 15. it should copy details of it and paste it next sheet

Comment: your example data does not show any s.no 15. Please see what a [mcve] is and provide the necessary code along with example input data and desired output. One line of code does not cover the actual problem.

Comment: @hammed If you're trying to copy `$A$2` to `$A$20`, you're only going to get column A. Ranges need to be `$A$2` to `$D$20` - is that your issue? What are you putting in the ranges on your userform input?

Comment: check it now I have updated

Comment: @hammed you see my comment?

Comment: You're also only pasting into one column (`B8:B37`). That should be `B8:E37` make sense?

Comment: @user1274820 how to write that exactly ,can you write it completely, im new for vba why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to copy `$A$2` to `$A$20`, you're only going to get column `A`.

Ranges need to be `$A$2` to `$D$20` - is that your issue?

You're also pasting into only one column (column `B`).

Try pasting into `B8:E37` as an example (or just specify the starting area for paste like `Range("B8")`)

---

Here is how your code would look updated.

It's very important that your `cellFrom1` and `cellTo1` contains the right column. Example: cellFrom1 = `$A$1` and cellTo1 = `$D$4`

```
Sub copy_data()
If pass1 = 1 Then
    Sheets("I yr").Range(cellFrom1 & ":" & cellTo1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8")
End If

If pass2 = 1 Then
    Sheets("II yr").Range(cellFrom2 & ":" & cellTo2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8")
End If

If pass3 = 1 Then
    Sheets("III yr").Range(cellFrom3 & ":" & cellTo3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8")
End If

If pass4 = 1 Then
    Sheets("IV yr").Range(cellFrom4 & ":" & cellTo4).Copy Destination:=Sheets("final").Range("B8")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: im using variables to save the values of from and to. so how alter it to work

Comment: The destination always seems to be the same sheet and same position, so I'm not sure if that's your intent, but see the code I posted.

Comment: my cellTo value will be like $A$4 ,how can get that like the $D$4 ?

Comment: my destination is seperate sheet name "final"

Comment: I mean like now my cellTo value is $A$10 but how can i make it change to $D$10 automatically in cellTo

Comment: and can i know know how to copy those data but without S.No, only Reg No ,Name,Year

Comment: Hey sorry for the slow reply @hammed - I just need to see where/how your `cellFrom` variables are being set. You can change them to whatever you need and modify them as needed in your code. Just depends on what you're trying to do

Comment: cellFrom1 = Sheets("I yr").Range("N4").Value.   It will take value of N4. In N4 I wrote a formula to take the address of the 'to' value

Comment: formula used to find the address of From and to "=CELL("address",INDEX(A:A,N3))"

Comment: If you need to shift the column in the formula, you can use `OFFSET` in your formula like this: `=CELL("address",OFFSET(INDEX(A:A,N3),0,4))` The `0,4` in offset lets you specify how many rows/columns to shift by. In this case, I shift by 4 columns to return the cell 4 columns to the right (`E`). You can also simplify the formula by just specifying the cell itself like this `=CELL("address",N3)` which becomes `=CELL("address",OFFSET(N3,0,4))` And it's worth noting that `N3` is a perfectly valid address all on its own. You don't have to use the dollar sign `$N$3` - those are absolute references.

Comment: Np - welcome to stackoverflow - happy to have you 

Comment: can you help me from this problem https://superuser.com/q/1753138/1748241